# Grub config separate root and boot partitions

Tags: grub2

I've been reading many articles about Grub with LOTS of examples for configuration. Exactly 0 contain configuration for a separate root and boot partition on LVM.

This is my configuration:

```
menuentry 'Kali' {
insmod lvm
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root=lvm/triagia-kaliboot
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f1eb6904-c17e-40b7-8740-60e67b8d04de
linux /vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/triagia-kaliboot setkmap=us
initrd /initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
}
```

And this is my LVM setup:

```
  sda3                 8:3    0 396.9G  0 part  
  ├─triagia-kaliboot 254:0    0   500M  0 lvm   
  ├─triagia-kaliroot 254:1    0    50G  0 lvm   
  └─triagia-kaliswap 254:2    0     4G  0 lvm
```

This boots up but does not initiate, I think I'm using the wrong config regarding where the / is and where the /boot is.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling the kernel to look for a root directory in: `root=/dev/mapper/triagia-kaliboot`. I think you need to change this.

Edit the kernel parameter used by GRUB2 to find a root directory by changing this line in your `/etc/default/grub`:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="root=/dev/mapper/triagia-kaliroot"` .

Since you are using LVM for your /boot partition under GRUB2, you also need to add this line to your `/etc/default/grub`:

`GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm"`.

When done issue an `# update-grub` or a `# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` command, and reboot.

Comment: I also boot another OS with this Grub so the LINUX_DEFAULT line allready contains this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=21f80129-085c-4f2d-9492-66adfd8d2ce2 quiet " and I am afraid that adding the root= part to this will break my other menu option. Thats why I try to solve this in 40_custom.

Comment: In that case I think its safe to edit your menuentry into the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file, just change the line `linux /vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/triagia-kaliboot setkmap=us` to `linux /vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/triagia-kaliroot setkmap=us`, and if you have not already done it, add the `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="lvm"` line to your `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I did try the line change for linux_default and now my system won't boot anymore and other systems can't find the LVM Volume Group on the disk. I give up on Grub + LVM + Luks and will erase the disk now. I'll look for something more stable.

Comment: I feel sure that there is a means to do what you are trying to do in editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, and sorry i could not help I've got an identical setup as yours except my `/boot` partition is not inside the LVM container.